# How to implement PERCENTw.d format without multiplication by hundred?

Tags: sas

I want to display as *PERCENT3.1* without multiplying the values by hundred, as they are already computed as percentages.

I tried this

```
proc format;
picture abc low-high='000.0%';
run;
```

and then using *abc.*

It shows values greater than 1, like 38.12 as 38.1% which is as desired, but for values less than 1, like 0.92 it shows as 9%

Are there any other methods to do this?

Comment: Proc format also takes functions so you could do the multiplication within the format to apply the standard percent format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your picture statement to have non-zero digit selectors on both the left and right hand side of the decimal point.  You will also want rounding to occur before the value is picture rendered.

Example:

```
proc format;
picture abc (round) low-high='009.9 %';
run;

data _null_;

  input x @@;
  put x= @10 x= abc.;
datalines;
100 38 38.12 3.14 3.19 3 0.92 0
;

----- LOG -----

x=100    x=100.0 %
x=38     x=38.0 %
x=38.12  x=38.1 %
x=3.14   x=3.1 %
x=3.19   x=3.2 %
x=3      x=3.0 %
x=0.92   x=0.9 %
x=0      x=0.0 %
```

Comment: Hi, may I ask what's the meaning of `9` on both sides of `.`?

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Hadn't encountered the significance of non-zero digit selectors till now.